# "Gain in popularity" vs "Gain popularity"?

Tags: word-usage

I've got the following sentence:

> These issues have allowed for alternatives, such as Spotify and Pandora, to gain in popularity.

A friend expressed concern and believes that it would be more correct to say:

> These issues have allowed for alternatives, such as Spotify and Pandora, to gain popularity.

Is there a de-facto correct usage here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my ear, "gain in popularity" means "become more popular," whereas "gain popularity" equals to saying "become popular."

> - "These issues have allowed for alternatives, such as Spotify and Pandora, to **gain in popularity**" means "Spotify" and "Pandora" are both popular alternatives that have become even more popular.
> - "These issues have allowed for alternatives, such as Spotify and Pandora, to **gain popularity**" means "Spotify" and "Pandora" were alternatives unknown to the general public that have become popular.

Comment: @SeanAnderson You're welcome. As an aside, this question is not specific to "popularity." Think of "gain prestige" vs. "gain in prestige," "gain strength" vs. "gain in strength," etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In most contexts there's no difference in meaning, but it's worth noting that the optional extra preposition in *gain **in** ["abstract quality" noun]* has never been the most popular form...

[image]

Also note that when it's followed by *another* preposition, we like it even less...

[image]

---

There are some contexts where including ***in*** implies that the specific abstract quality *was already present, albeit to a lesser degree*. This is purely my own opinion, but I think that to a considerable extent, *credibility*, for example, is the kind of abstract quality that something either has or doesn't have. In which case I'd interpret the construction as *gain = acquire* rather that *gain = increase*...

[image]

Although I can't claim the ***in*** version there has *completely* "flatlined", I probably wouldn't use it.